# Sunspot order_by sort with nil values being last

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am trying to order the Sunspot search results by price from the smaller to bigger values.

```
order_by :price, :asc
```

However there are some items which have nil price values. They are placed at the front of results. Is there a good way to display those at the end instead of leaving them out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add an attribute "sortMissingLast=true" to the price field's definition in the schema.xml

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should should add sortMissingLast=true to the field in schema.xml, something like this:

```
<schema name="sunspot" version="1.0">
  <types>
    ...
    <!-- My custom types -->
    <fieldType name="sml_int" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
  </types>
  <fields>
    ...
    <!-- My custom fields -->
    <dynamicField name="*_sml_int" type="sml_int" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
  </fields>
  ...
</schema>
```

Then in your code you can do this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    integer :price, as: :price_sml_int
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use property **sortMissingLast="true"** in fieldType of the field in **schema.xml**.

Restart solr server.

(Implicit default value is false.)